# Is there a difference between .JPG and .jpg?

Tags: php, image-processing, upload, image-compression

below code generate thumbnail and create compress image and upload image.

```
if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];          //3             

    define ("MAX_SIZE","400");
    function getExtension($str) {
        $i = strrpos($str,".");
        if (!$i) { return ""; }
        $l = strlen($str) - $i;
        $ext = substr($str,$i+1,$l);
        return $ext;
    }

    $errors=0;

    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        $image =$_FILES["file"]["name"];
        $uploadedfile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

        if ($image) {
            $filename = stripslashes($_FILES['file']['name']);
            $extension = getExtension($filename);
            $extension = strtolower($extension);

            if (($extension != "jpg") && ($extension != "jpeg") && ($extension != "png") && ($extension != "gif")) {
                $change='<div class="msgdiv">Unknown Image extension </div> ';
                $errors=1;
            } else {
                $size=filesize($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);

                if ($size > MAX_SIZE*1024) {
                    $change='<div class="msgdiv">You have exceeded the size limit!</div> ';
                    $errors=1;
                }


                if($extension=="jpg" || $extension=="jpeg" ) {
                    $uploadedfile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
                    $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($uploadedfile);
                } else if($extension=="png") {
                    $uploadedfile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
                    $src = imagecreatefrompng($uploadedfile);
                } else {
                    $src = imagecreatefromgif($uploadedfile);
                }
                echo $scr;
                list($width,$height)=getimagesize($uploadedfile);

                $newwidth=600;
                $newheight=($height/$width)*$newwidth;
                $tmp=imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth,$newheight);

                $newwidth1=125;
                $newheight1=($height/$width)*$newwidth1;
                $tmp1=imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth1,$newheight1);
                imagecopyresampled($tmp,$src,0,0,0,0,$newwidth,$newheight,$width,$height);
                        imagecopyresampled($tmp1,$src,0,0,0,0,$newwidth1,$newheight1,$width,$height);

                $file_name = date('d') . date('M') . $_FILES['file']['name'];
                $filename = "upload/gallery/". $file_name;
                $filename1 = "upload/thumb/". $file_name;

                imagejpeg($tmp,$filename,100);
                imagejpeg($tmp1,$filename1,100);
                imagedestroy($src);
                imagedestroy($tmp);
                imagedestroy($tmp1);
            }
        }
    }     
}
```

Result is some image store with .JPG extension or some of stored with .jpg
But, main problem is occurred that files that have uppercase extensions (specifically .JPG) are not opening or being recognized in Windows Live Photo Gallery. .jpg files work as expected. What could be causing this issue?

Comment: there is absolutely no difference, except that some badly-written programs don't recognize JPG.

Comment: Rename it to lower-case, you might have a bad time when your server is running on linux

Comment: Also you can replace your file extension getter with `$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);` Maybe your extension getter has a woopsy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are lower casing the extension before all the test for the correct extension type etc, but when you come to save the file you are using whatever is in the raw `$_FILES['file']['name']`

```
$file_name = date('d') . date('M') . $_FILES['file']['name'];
```

So do a strtolower on the raw filename as well before saving the file

```
$file_name = date('d') . date('M') . strtolower($_FILES['file']['name']);
```